# Nested array if value is equal add object to array in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to iterate through a nested for loop. If a value if equals to something, I want to add that object to an array in my state.

```
this.state = {
    custBehavior: [],
    custService: [],
    custEngagement: [],
    custUsage: []
  }
```

Code

```
this.props.insights.map((behavior) =>
  behavior.map((items) =>
    {if (items.scoreCategory === "Behavior") {
      this.setState(behaviorInsight => ({
        custBehavior: [...behaviorInsight.custBehavior, items]
      }))
    }}
  )
```

The prop information is the full JSON below.

If I remove the if statement and do this....

```
this.props.insights.map((behavior) =>
  behavior.map((items) =>
    console.log(items)
  )
);
```

I'll get a print out of each object within the array; again, sample JSON is below.

```
[{
            "scoreModelId": "DNA_APPLE_HML_TAG",
            "scoreDisplayName": "Apple Enthusiast",
            "scoreCategory": "Behavior",
            "scoreSystem": "LMH",
            "scoreValue": "HIGH",
            "scoreDate": "2019-01-05",
            "scoreLevel": "L",
            "scorePriority": 1
        }, {
            "scoreModelId": "DNA_GOOGLE_HML_TAG",
            "scoreDisplayName": "Google Enthusiast",
            "scoreCategory": "Behavior",
            "scoreSystem": "LMH",
            "scoreValue": "HIGH",
            "scoreDate": "2019-01-05",
            "scoreLevel": "L",
            "scorePriority": 1
        }, {
            "scoreModelId": "MG6M_IN_A",
            "scoreDisplayName": "LTV Model",
            "scoreCategory": "Segmentation",
            "scoreSystem": "DECIMAL",
            "scoreValue": "14.06",
            "scoreDecile": "2",
            "scoreCentile": "13",
            "scoreDate": "2019-01-14",
            "scoreLevel": "L"
        }]
```

I can't see what I am missing here.

Comment: Please don't post sample data as images. Use text format instead.

Comment: updated with sample data @hindmost

Comment: I meant **all** data in your post

Comment: that is all of the data.

Comment: Replace _**all images**_ in the post with text.

Comment: there is only two images... which is the json data i put in there... you seem to be confused... :)

Comment: You should avoid using images to represent textual data (such as JSON). So replace that images ("the prop information" and "I get the following.") with corresponding JSON

Comment: ok, thanks dad. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it by using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). You can then add each `items` to your final array by filtering every behavior objects.

You should only ever set your state once since it is an asynchronous function

```
const custBehavior = this.props.insights.reduce(
    (acc, behavior) => [...acc, ...behavior.filter(items => items.scoreCategory === "Behavior")], //Takes out every item corresponding to the filter and adds them to the final array
    [] //The starting value, an empty array
)
this.setState({ custBehavior })
```

To apply it to other types you could make a function out of the above code :

```
customCategory = (category, name) => {
    const custThing = this.props.insights.reduce(
        (acc, behavior) => [...acc, ...behavior.filter(items => items.scoreCategory === category)],
        []
    )
    this.setState({ [name]: custThing })
}

//

this.customCategory('Behavior', 'custBehavior')
this.customCategory('Segmentation', 'yourStateVariableName')
```

The `state` variable name will be set using computed properties and the filter argument is given via the function parameter too.

Comment: thanks! since I have a few other objects to look for, you can see in my data Segmentation is another, how would this work with other arrays? You can see my state has a total of four arrays ill be using

Comment: Well, I guess it depends on what you want to achieve with he other arrays, you could simply change the string in the `filter` in the best case. Could you post a sample input/output ?

Comment: i posted the same json above. in that sample, there was a scorecategory of segmentation. i eventually need to put the data in four specific areas.

Comment: so, your code works with the Behavior category, if I wanted to add the other category in there (Segmentation) how would I go about doing that.

Comment: I edited my answer, is this what you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to normalize the data and then change the state

Eg:

```js
const normalizedData = this.props.insights.map((behavior) =>
  behavior.map((items) =>
    if (items.scoreCategory === "Behavior") {
      return ({
        custBehavior: [...behaviorInsight.custBehavior, items]
      })
    }
  ).filter(value => value)

  this.setState({ custBehavior: normalizedData })
```